# How to improve my code to fill an array from a text table?

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures, io

I'm a research assistant at a mental health clinic, and I'm trying to write a C program which will convert raw scores (on four subtests) into T scores. C, for better or for worse, is the language I'm most familiar with, but it's been a while since I've written anything, so please excuse my ignorance.

Each raw score on each subtest only corresponds to one T score. However, the converse doesn't hold: Each T score can correspond to multiple raw scores (especially at either extreme of the scale), and some T scores don't correspond to any raw scores.

My solution to the problem of representing this data in a text file is to represent the data in eight columns, every odd column (indices [0], [2], [4], and [6]) representing the T score and every even column representing the raw score that corresponds to it, which seems to solve this for now. If a T score doesn't have a corresponding raw score, I've inserted -1 to keep fscanf happy.

However, I was hoping that maybe you can help me work out a more intelligent solution. I'm also wondering if there's a better data structure that will allow me to intelligently represent and manipulate the asymmetric relationship between T scores and raw scores, maybe so that there would be one entry for each T score and a range of possible values for the subtests that could yield that T score? The file looks like this:

```
20,0,20,0,20,-1,20,0
20,1,20,1,21,-1,20,1
20,2,20,2,22,0,20,2
20,3,20,3,23,1,20,3
20,4,20,4,24,2,20,4
20,5,20,5,25,3,20,5
20,6,20,6,26,4,20,6
20,7,20,7,27,5,20,7
20,8,20,8,28,6,20,8
20,9,20,9,29,7,20,9
```

You can see what I have so far below. It does the following:

1. Using a for loop and a two-dimensional integer array, it retrieves the data from the file and enters it into the array.

   The table has 83 rows, so I capped the loop at 83 iterations, but I'm sure there must be a better way to do this so I won't have to hard-code it into the program (I was thinking maybe a while loop that stops when a certain number, like -2, is detected?).

   The -1 trick seems to work for now, but I'm also hoping there's a better way to process the table input so that I can use it as is. But I don't really understand the syntax for `fscanf` well enough to implement something better. Could you give me any pointers on that?
2. Using further for loops, it runs through the raw score rows and checks for identity between the score the user has entered and its place in the table. I was wondering if there's a clever way to nest these operations into a superordinate for loop?
3. When the numbers match up, a T score is assigned and the results are printed.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int tab[8][83];
  int r_v, r_s, r_bd, r_mr;
  int t_v, t_s, t_bd, t_mr;
  int i;
  FILE *input;

  input = fopen(argv[1], "r");

  printf("Subtest A score?\n");
  scanf("%i", &r_v);

  printf("Subtest B score?\n");
  scanf("%i", &r_s);

  printf("Subtest C score?\n");
  scanf("%i", &r_bd);

  printf("Subtest D score?\n");
  scanf("%i", &r_mr);

  for (i = 0; i < 83; i++) {
    fscanf(input, "%i,%i,%i,%i,%i,%i,%i,%i", &tab[0][i], &tab[1][i], &tab[2][i], &tab[3][i], &tab[4][i], &tab[5][i], &tab[6][i], &tab[7][i]);
    }

  for (i = 0; i < 83; i++) {
    if (r_v == tab[1][i]) {
      t_v = tab[0][i];
    }
  }

  for (i = 0; i < 83; i++) {
    if (r_s == tab[3][i]) {
      t_s = tab[2][i];
    }
  }

  for (i = 0; i < 83; i++) {
    if (r_bd == tab[5][i]) {
      t_bd = tab[4][i];
    }
  }

  for (i = 0; i < 83; i++) {
    if (r_mr == tab[7][i]) {
      t_mr = tab[6][i];
    }
  }

  printf("The participant had the following raw scores: %d, %d, %d, and %d.\n", r_v, r_s, r_bd, r_mr);
  printf("Which corresponds to the following T scores: %d, %d, %d, and %d.\n", t_v, t_s, t_bd, t_mr);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Error Handling

To start, the posted code lacks error-checking. The user may fail to provide a file name, or may provide a non-existent file name. The file may fail to open. The user may enter non-numeric input. The input values may not be found in the table.

Failure to provide a file name can be caught by checking `argc` at the beginning of the program. Failure to open the file can be handled by checking the value returned from `fopen()` and exiting with a message when a null pointer is returned.

If an input value is not found in the table, no value is stored in the associated variable. One way of handling this problem is to initialize the associated variable to a sentinel value which is not expected in the table. I have chosen `-1` in the code below.

To handle user input, a `get_integer()` function could be added which takes an input prompt message as an argument and returns the input number. If the user enters malformed input, the function continues to prompt for the input until correct input is given. This function can also validate that input is a non-negative integer, to guard against assigning a value based on a user input value of `-1`.

One refinement might be to place an upper limit on how many times a user may provide bad input before exiting the program with a message.

### Data Structure

Instead of storing the table as a 2d array and accessing the individual fields of the table through indices, I would suggest creating a structure for the lines of the table, and a `table[]` array of these `struct`s. This would allow for descriptive field names and make the code much more clear.

### Reading the File

I would suggest using `fgets()` to fetch lines from the file. This function returns a null pointer when end-of-file has been reached, allowing control with a `while` loop. The `sscanf()` function can be used to parse each line and to store values in the appropriate locations. As with all functions which return meaningful values, the value returned from `sscanf()` should be checked to be sure that input is as expected. If not, the situation can be handled, perhaps by exiting the program with an error message. I would also consider constructing the table from the file *before* asking for more user input.

As each line is successfully added to the table, a `line` counter can be incremented to keep track of the number of rows in the `table[]` array.

### Searching the Table

Only one loop is needed here. The `line` counter can be used to establish the upper bound on the number of rows to be checked. As OP has suggested that each search value is unique, once it has been found and stored the associated variable will not be changed again. If a search value is not found in the table, the associated variable continues to hold the initial value (`-1`).

A refinement would be to add a flag to indicate when all search values have been found, and to break out of the loop early when this occurs.

Here is an example program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_ROWS  100
#define BUF_SZ    1024

struct Record
{
    int t_v;
    int r_v;
    int t_s;
    int r_s;
    int t_bd;
    int r_bd;
    int t_mr;
    int r_mr;
};

int get_integer(const char *prompt);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct Record table[MAX_ROWS];
    int r_v, r_s, r_bd, r_mr;
    int t_v = -1;
    int t_s = -1;
    int t_bd = -1;
    int t_mr = -1;
    FILE *input;

    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s filename\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    input = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if (input == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file: %s\n", argv[1]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Read table  into array */
    int line = 0;
    char buffer[BUF_SZ];
    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, input) != NULL) {
        if (sscanf(buffer, "%i,%i,%i,%i,%i,%i,%i,%i",
                   &table[line].t_v,
                   &table[line].r_v,
                   &table[line].t_s,
                   &table[line].r_s,
                   &table[line].t_bd,
                   &table[line].r_bd,
                   &table[line].t_mr,
                   &table[line].r_mr)
            != 8) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Format error in line %d\n", line);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        ++line;
    }
    fclose(input);

    r_v = get_integer("Subtest A score?\n");
    r_s = get_integer("Subtest B score?\n");
    r_bd = get_integer("Subtest C score?\n");
    r_mr = get_integer("Subtest D score?\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < line; i++) {
        if (r_v == table[i].r_v) {
            t_v = table[i].t_v;
        }
        if (r_s == table[i].r_s) {
            t_s = table[i].t_s;
        }
        if (r_bd == table[i].r_bd) {
            t_bd = table[i].t_bd;
        }
        if (r_mr == table[i].r_mr) {
            t_mr = table[i].t_mr;
        }
    }

    printf("The participant had the following raw scores: "
           "%d, %d, %d, and %d.\n",
           r_v, r_s, r_bd, r_mr);
    printf("Which corresponds to the following T scores: "
           "%d, %d, %d, and %d.\n",
           t_v, t_s, t_bd, t_mr);

    return 0;
}

int get_integer(const char *prompt)
{
    char buf[BUF_SZ];
    int ret;

    do {
        printf("%s", prompt);
        fflush(stdout);
        if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Input error in get_integer()\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    } while (sscanf(buf, "%i", &ret) != 1 || ret < 0);

    return ret;
}
```

And here is an example interaction using the posted input file:

```
λ> ./tvals t_vals.dat
Subtest A score?
3
Subtest B score?
4
Subtest C score?
5
Subtest D score?
6
The participant had the following raw scores: 3, 4, 5, and 6.
Which corresponds to the following T scores: 20, 20, 27, and 20.
```

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer! I will consider this carefully and maybe post a couple of questions if I have any.

Comment: I like the use of `fgets` in `get_integer`, but you may want to at least warn on *invalid* input in addition to repeating the prompt to insure the user knows it isn't stuck. Something like `int err = 0; .. do { if (!err) err = 1; else fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n"); printf("%s", prompt); ...`

Answer (score 0):

Uhmm.. i didn't get that code very well.
As i can see, if A score is 5, `t_v` is 20 (either if a score was 0).
I don't see you loaded the values in the file to the `tab` matrix.
So `tab` is unitialized too.
Anothed thing if you want to improve your code.
You made 5 loops.. when you can simply merge all these into one.
A`for`loop with at the top there's `fscanf` and after it all your conditions.

Comment: 1. That's correct, if A is 5, t_v should be 20, but also if A is 0, or 1, or 2, and so on. As we get further down the table (I didn't post all of it here), the T values increase.



2. "I don't see you loaded the values in the file to the tab matrix. So tab is unitialized too." Isn't that what this piece of code does?

    for (i = 0; i < 83; i++) {
    fscanf(input, "%i,%i,%i,%i,%i,%i,%i,%i", &tab[0][i], &tab[1][i], &tab[2][i], &tab[3][i], &tab[4][i], &tab[5][i], &tab[6][i], &tab[7][i]);
    }

Comment: Ok yes is that.
So.. what's the problem?
As i said, you can merge all the loops to one

Comment: I'm not sure it is that easy, because each raw score could correspond to a different T value, so that r_v might intersect with t_v at a different point in the table (i.e., at a different value for i) than r_bd intersects with t_bd. Running it all through the same for loop counter would probably give rise to all manner of issues.

Comment: @DavidBowling — I see, thanks. I'm not sure that's a problem, as each raw score (so indices [1], [3], [5], and [7]) uniquely determines one T score, so there can only be one matching entry (I think?). Of course this all hinges on sane input values, which I sort of just take for granted as I will probably be the only person using the program!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NO_OF_ROW       100     //You can change if no of rows increases
#define EACH_LINE_SIZE  100

#define SUBTEST_A       1
#define SUBTEST_B       3
#define SUBTEST_C       5
#define SUBTEST_D       7

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int tab[8][NO_OF_ROW] = {{0}};
    int r_v, r_s, r_bd, r_mr;
    int t_v=0, t_s=0, t_bd=0, t_mr=0;
    int i;
    FILE *input;
    int no_rows =0;

    char* line = malloc(EACH_LINE_SIZE);

    input = fopen("User.txt", "r");

    if(NULL == input)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    printf("Subtest A score?\n");
    scanf("%i", &r_v);

    printf("Subtest B score?\n");
    scanf("%i", &r_s);

    printf("Subtest C score?\n");
    scanf("%i", &r_bd);

    printf("Subtest D score?\n");
    scanf("%i", &r_mr);

    while (fgets(line, EACH_LINE_SIZE, input) != NULL)
    {
        sscanf(line, "%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d", &tab[0][i], &tab[1][i], &tab[2][i], &tab[3][i], &tab[4][i], &tab[5][i], &tab[6][i], &tab[7][i]);
        //printf("%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d\n", tab[0][i], tab[1][i], tab[2][i], tab[3][i], tab[4][i], tab[5][i], tab[6][i], tab[7][i]);
        i++;
        if(NO_OF_ROW <= i)
        {
            printf("Stop file reading \n");
            break;          //if the file has more line -Just end it here
        }
    }

    no_rows = i;

    for(i=0 ; i < no_rows ; i++)
    {
        if (r_v == tab[SUBTEST_A][i])
        {
            t_v = tab[SUBTEST_A-1][i];
        }

        if (r_s == tab[SUBTEST_B][i])
        {
            t_s = tab[SUBTEST_B-1][i];
        }

        if (r_bd == tab[SUBTEST_C][i])
        {
            t_bd = tab[SUBTEST_C-1][i];
        }
        if (r_mr == tab[SUBTEST_D][i])
        {
            t_mr = tab[SUBTEST_D-1][i];
        }
    }

    printf("The participant had the following raw scores: %d, %d, %d, and %d.\n", r_v, r_s, r_bd, r_mr);
    printf("Which corresponds to the following T scores: %d, %d, %d, and %d.\n", t_v, t_s, t_bd, t_mr);

    free(line);

    return 0;
}
```

1. Instead of constant 83, tried with different method, so you can vary the number of lines
2. Also instead of 4 loops, tried to fit in single for loop

Comment: You **must** validate the return of `sscanf`. Failure to do so will result in *Undefined Behavior* with any variation of input format. The same applies for ALL *User Input*, especially with `scanf`. What happens is the `g` key is accidentally pressed during user input? Simple rule, if you take input, *validate it*.